# query sql between two tables

Tags: sql, linq, sql-server-2012

i tried query but no have search answer, i have two tables

[image: table 1]

[image]

i want design a query in Linq  that get all data that have register in table 2 with value in number field 1 AND value 3 AND value 4 , in this example i get data of the table 1

[image]

thanks for you collaboration

Comment: why votes negatives ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd go about it - I wrote it in SQL because I'm WAY better at that than I am at LINQ, but converting from one to the other should be straightforward:

```
select 
    t1.id
    , t1.value
from table1 as t1
    inner join table2 as t21
        on t21.idTable1 = t1.id
        and t21.number = 1
    inner join table2 as t23
        on t23.idTable1 = t1.id
        and t23.number = 3
    inner join table2 as t24
        on t24.idTable1 = t1.id
        and t24.number = 4
```

This joins to a subset of Table 2 three times, once for each value that you want.  Using "inner join" makes the logic equivalent to an AND.

Answer (score 0):

**by using sub query**

select * from table_1 where id in (select idtable1 from table_2 where number in (1,3,4))

**by joints**
select * from table_1 t1 join table_2 t2 on t1.id=t2.idtable1 where t2.number in (1,3,4)

Answer (score 0):

it would be

```
select id,idTable1,number 
       from 
       table2 
 where idTable1 = 1
```

if i'm understanding the question correctly. Your question is a bit hard to grasp. IF there should be a join in there its

```
   select b.id,a.Idtable1,a.number
     from table1 b ,table2 a 
     where b.id = a.Idtable1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken about what you want, this might work. You need to join the to tables and then check for the condition that you want using where.

```
SELECT a.id, a.value
FROM TABLE1 a
INNER JOIN TABLE2 b on a.id=b.idTable1
WHERE b.number in (1,3,4)
AND a.id = 1;
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, but it is wrong because with sentence "in", i get data only to meets a conditions, i want get register that have number 1 and other register in number 3 and other register in value 4, i think that with sentence "union" could working

Answer (score 0):

This first query assumes that table2.number is unique for a given id.  That might not be true.  If it is:

```
select table1.id, table1.value
from table1 
join table2 
  on table1.id = table2.idTable1
group by table1.id, table1.value
having count(*) = 3
where table2.number in (1,3,4)
```

If 'number' could be a repeating value (is not unique for each idTable1), then we need to make sure we're joining on distinct values in table2:

```
select table1.id, table1.value
from table1 
join (select distinct table2.idTable1, table2.number where table2.number in (1,3,4)) t2 
  on table1.id = t2.idTable1
group by table1.id, table1.value
having count(*) = 3
```